# Applied Rational Choice Theory

Tags: logic, mathematical-modeling, economics

I am a programmer researching the application of Rational Choice Theory.
I have found many links to the philosophical nature of it.
And fewer documents formalizing it's mathematical principles. ( https://web.stanford.edu/~jdlevin/Econ%20202/Choice%20Theory.pdf )

While these are good resources for a basic understanding, As an engineer, I am looking for resources on how "Rational Choice" models are built.

While my internet searches describe how to formalize their mathematical properties, I am looking for some concrete examples on how to build such a model.

For example: I am sure that someone is using some common regression techniques to find equilibriums, but I have yet to find a good learning resource with examples of how to extract one from the assumptions. Or how would one extract a utility function from given data?

As I don't have an economics background I might be searching for the wrong keywords on google.

Comment: I'm not positive what you're looking for.  Given an interest of rational choice are you interested in the empirical techniques used to test it?  Or rather just an overview of its application in mathematical economics?

Comment: The latter, I'd like read an example from start to finish detailing which methods were used to build a model. For example:  http://business.baylor.edu/steve_green/green1.doc details the conclusions from modelling the church scenario, but does not detail the work on how these conclusions were reached. Also, I assume that there is a way to derive the utility function from a real statistical sample ( am I wrong? ), and I'm looking for an example of that being done.

Comment: In terms of interests then it sounds like you're just generally interested in most micro-economic models.  Now, the problem really is that most micro-economics of interest treats preferences only at the level of assuming the existence of a utility function that embodies them; you'll almost never see an explicit derivation of utilities from preferences in places where that alone is not the main point of the exercise.  Once you have a utility function though, the sky's the limit.

Comment: Now, in that vein if you're more interested in a technical discussion of what must be assumed on preferences to get well-behaved utility functions, I can give you some references, but often in the theoretical model side of things getting a utility function out of primitives is just done by fiat.  Empirically, estimating preferences is very hard, and generally done under very strong assumptions on functional form etc.  If you're specifically interested in seeing that/the complications that arise, I'd also be happy to give you some references/discussion.

Comment: I'm a beginner and not an economical theorist. I would like to witness some real world use cases of using rational choice theory. At the end of which, I do not expect to understand rational choice theory, but rather understand: "What is rational choice theory good for?", and "is it applicable to my field"? (mass transit simulations). As such I am less interested in complications, but rather more interested in "naive success stories". What we would call in computer science, the "hello world" of Rational Choice Theory. The problem is that intro courses are theoretical, rather than applied.

Comment: In this case, I think the lack of applied courses is actually telling, in that generally speaking there aren't (any, that I can think of) applied works (barring experiments testing RCT) that 'directly' use RCT.  RCT serves more a role akin to ZFC in mathematics: it provides a set of conditions under which one can assure the existence of an infinitely more useful utility function encoding those preferences.  Applied work usually begins at level of assuming utility functions, not at the preference level then deriving utility.   Analogously, no 'hello world' code begins in assembly.

Comment: If you're interested in seeing *how* one gets from the preferences of RCT up to utility functions, I'd be happy to provide you with proofs/derivations.  If you're interested in what RCT could bring to your field in general though, I'd suggest instead look at how *utility functions* get used in applied work, rather than preferences themselves.  If you tell me more about the problem you're hoping to solve I can try to point you in a more specific direction too.